# LinearLayout inside a ToolBar is not matching parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I put a LinearLayout1 in the ToolBar.Then another 5 LinearLayouts in the LinearLayout1. Each child LinearLayout has an ImageView. Here my problem is that the LinearLayout1 is not matching parent width.That I have showed in the image(in red circle). The black color is the background that I have given to the ToolBar.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/featured_bottomToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/menu_black_featured"
                android:id="@+id/imageView" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/menu_grey_justin2"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/menu_grey_designers"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/menu_grey_categories"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/meny_grey_more2"
                android:id="@+id/imageView5" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

The output I have got.

[image]

Comment: post code so we can help you.

Comment: Are you using a toolbar to manually create a tabhost?

Comment: I have posted. Please go through it and help.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Add the following properties to your `Toolbar` element.

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

Default value of `contentInsetStart` is `16dp`. You would need to set it to `0`.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/featured_bottomToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu_black_featured"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu_grey_justin2"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu_grey_designers"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu_grey_categories"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/meny_grey_more2"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have added : //in outer layout 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

// in tool bar
 app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
 app:contentInsetStart="0dp"

Answer (score 0):

Try calling:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.featured_bottomToolbar);
mToolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
```

on your `Toolbar` instance.

Answer (score -1):

**You also need to do:**

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Comment: It's useless and crashes if you use own toolbar.