# Android Toolbar / LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-toolbar

Good day everyone! I want to know why did my linear layout have margin in left? I want to set the linear layout, in the end of the left screen of the device.
[image]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_margin="0dp"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#32333D"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:text="Hello"/>
            </LinearLayout>

     </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

   </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You're using a Toolbar. There's a label for the app name inside the toolbar which probably causes that space. Try using another container (if you really need one) or please explain why you're using the toolbar widget in that place

Comment: Already solve it by this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874803/linearlayout-inside-a-toolbar-is-not-matching-parent

thanks.